# Statistical mean of measured values

Tags: experimental-physics

How to find the average value and error(uncertainty) from sets of values of the same variable obtained from instruments of different least count?

Comment: You should be more specific. What kind of error are you referring to? Just the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) or an [error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).  Maybe it would help if you describe what you are measuring.

Comment: The average value of the quantity and the average value of the error is the required final answer. For addition of quantities, the errors are added up.

Comment: It is a set of temperatures measured over a period of 50 years. For the first 12 years it is measured with a mercury thermometer of least count 1 degree and for the next 17 years another mercury thermometer of least count 0.5 degree is employed. For the last 21 years, an electronic device with least count 0.1 degree is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have $n$ data points of the same variable $x_i$ with uncertainty $\sigma_i$. For simplicity we assume that the errors of the different measurement apparatuses are independent and purely statistical. The weight $w_i$ of each measurement is given by

$$
w_i = \frac{1}{{\sigma_i}^2}.
$$

A common way to determine the average value is to calculate the weighted mean

$$
\bar{x}=\frac{\sum w_i x_i}{\sum w_i}
$$

and the average error is given by 
$$
\bar{\sigma}_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum \!w_i}}.
$$